# How does the ask function know the enrivonment to return in the Reader monad?

Tags: haskell

I'm reading this example on the Reader monad: https://blog.ssanj.net/posts/2014-09-23-A-Simple-Reader-Monad-Example.html that has this code:

```
import Control.Monad.Reader

tom :: Reader String String
tom = do
    env <- ask -- gives you the environment which in this case is a String
    return (env ++ " This is Tom.")
```

I understood what it does but I do not understand how `ask` can return anything.

In Haskell, functions can act on many different types. `ask` is a function that has no input and returns the monad environment `m r`. I'm trying to understand what happens when I do

```
(runReader tom) "Who is this?"
```

Somehow, `runReader` will call `tom`, but how is it possible that the `ask` inside `tom` will be able to return an `env` with the text `Who is this?`?

Comment: `ask` isn’t a function with no input; it’s a `Reader r r` *action* with no input, which is a `newtype` wrapper for a function of *one* input (like all functions), of type `r -> r`. In fact, `runReader` is equivalent to the identity function `id @(r -> a) :: (r -> a) -> (r -> a)`, since it just unwraps this wrapper so you can apply the function, and `ask` is also `id @r :: r -> r`, since it just returns the “environment” argument directly. `return`/`pure` is equivalent to `const`, for ignoring the environment, and `do` becomes `>>=`, which passes the environment along to each action.

Comment: By the way, you can write `runReader tom "Who is this?"` instead. In general, `f a b` is just syntactic sugar for `(f a) b` in Haskell.

Answer (score 6):

Every line of the `do` block in a Reader monad gets sent a copy of the environment in the background as if it had been passed in as an extra argument (and thanks to Haskell not having mutable data each one gets the same copy). The `ask` function takes its copy returns it as the value as well.

It would help to replace the generic `m` in the type of `ask` with concrete type: `ask::Reader r r`. This reads `ask` is a monadic action whose value(the second r) is the same as the environment (the first r). In order for `ask` to be useful a `Reader r` context must be present (that is what the `do` block is there for). Within that context `r` is always sitting there waiting to be used.

Think for a moment about how you might write this example without the Monad:

```
tom :: String -> String
tom env = env ++ " This is Tom."

jerry :: String -> String
jerry env = env ++ " This is Tom."

tomAndJerry :: String -> String
tomAndJerry env = 
  let
    t = tom env
    j = jerry env
   in (t ++"\n"++j)
```

Notice how `env` gets manually passed to each function? (This is by the way exactly what you get if you substitute the definition of `Reader r`, `ask` and `runReader` into the example.) The Reader monad simply wraps up the process of collecting and passing on the environment for us which is nice because it is a process we are prone to mess up (at least I am).

Reader Monads are really handy when you have a configuration file you read once at start up and then reference throughout the rest of the program.  In imperative languages you might make it a global const variable. In Haskell you could try to pass that value into every function that needed it, but it is easier and less bug prone to dump it into a Reader monad (and the result is exactly the same just without all the typing.)  This comes with this side benefit of the type system tagging all the functions that depend on the config file so when the configuration format changes the compiler can point out all the places that might need to be updated.

Answer (score 4):

I think you basically struggle with the definition of `Reader` and how it is used.

So let's quickly build our own:

```hs
newtype MyReader env a = MyReader (env -> a)
```

that's right a `Reader` can be just a *function* that takes the current environment and returns some `a` - here in a `newtype` wrapper so we can define some instances on it without much *extensions*

`runReader` is really simple - it just applies the given environment to our wrapped function:

```hs
runReader :: MyReader env a -> env -> a
runReader (MyReader f) = f
```

that should probably answer most of your question - `runReader` will not call `tom` in your example - you provide it as an argument so *you* call the wrapped function with `tom` ;)

---

But let's finish our Monad

So let's start by making this a functor - GHC by now could derive it but I guess for understanding doing it by hand is better:

```hs
instance Functor (MyReader env) where
  fmap f (MyReader rdr) = MyReader (f . rdr)
```

if you look closely you'll see that this is indeed just *function composition* - so the mapped reader will take an `env`, apply the wrapped function to it and after this `f` to this outcome.

*Applicative* is next:

```hs
instance Applicative (MyReader env) where
  pure a = MyReader (\_ -> a)
  (MyReader f_a_to_b) <*> (MyReader f_a) = MyReader (\env -> f_a_to_b env (f_a env))
```

This should be easy enough - `pure a` is a reader that ignores the environment and returns the value given to `pure` no matter what.

And you `<*>` two readers by providing the environment to both (I hope the naming helps - the first argument is a `MyReader env (a -> b)` the second a `MyReader env a` and the outcome should be `MyReader env b`)

Now we can define the monad instance:

```hs
instance Monad (MyReader env) where
  (MyReader f_a) >>= f_a_MyR_b = 
    MyReader (\env -> let a = f_a env in runReader (f_a_MyR_b a) env)
```

So this (as the *applicative*) passes a environment provided to the resulting `MyReader` to both parts. Here using `runReader` to make it a bit simpler (didn't want to unpack yet again).

---

Now for `ask` this one seems a bit special: it will bring the passed *environment*  right *into* the monad. You could probably figure it out from it's type: `ask :: MyReader env env` **try!** but here it is:

```hs
ask :: MyReader env env
ask = MyReader (\env -> env)
```

So back to your question:

> How ask can return anything?

it does only when really when you `runReader` it:

Take this simple example:

```hs
tom :: Reader String String
tom = do
    env <- ask -- gives you the environment which in this case is a String
    return (env ++ " This is Tom.")
```

it desugars to:

```hs
tom = ask >>= (\a -> pure (a ++ " This is Tom."))
```

and so if you do `runReader tom "Who is this"` and follow all the definitions above you end up with

```hs
runReader tom "Who is this"
  = let a = (\env -> env) "Who is this" in  (\env -> a ++ " This is Tom.") "Who is this"
  = let a = "Who is this" in a ++ " This is Tom."
  = "Who is this This is Tom".
```

---

### don't define `Functor`/`Applicative` yourself

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

import Control.Monad (ap)

newtype MyReader env a = 
  MyReader { runReader :: env -> a }
  deriving Functor

instance Applicative (MyReader env) where
  pure = return
  (<*>) = ap

instance Monad (MyReader env) where
  return a = MyReader (const a)
  (MyReader mr_a) >>= f_a_mr_b = 
    MyReader (\env -> let a = mr_a env in runReader (f_a_mr_b a) env)

ask :: MyReader env env
ask = MyReader id
```

Comment: why did you list the Applicative and Functor instances before the monad? The monad instance does not depend on them, I guess. I went to read about applicative and functors after your answer and came back here and still don't get why you did it

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs if you look at the definition of the [`Monad`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Monad) class you see `class Applicative m => Monad m` that means an instance of `Monad` *needs* to be an instance of `Applicative` - same with `Applicative`/`Functor` - that's why I did. For example `return` from `Monad` is just defined as `return = pure` from `Applicative` (you could override this but it makes no sense)

Comment: Of course every `Monad` is *always* a `Applicative`/`Functor` and I could have just written down definitions for `return`/`>>=` and derive everything from those but IMO that's more complicated than doing it this way and maybe less informative as well.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs I've added a section demonstrating how to implement `MyReader` without manually specifying `Applicative` or `Functor` - with `{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}` you can even strip the `Applicative` and just do `deriving (Functor, Applicative)` but than it's not as obvious that `(<*>) = ap` and `pure = return`. If you want you can play with this - comment out the `deriving` or the `Applicative` instance and see what happens