# How can the reader monad be bound like this

Tags: haskell, monads

```
import Control.Monad.Reader

tom :: Reader String String
tom = do
    env <- ask -- gives you the environment which in this case is a String
    return (env ++ " This is Tom.")

jerry :: Reader String String
jerry = do
  env <- ask
  return (env ++ " This is Jerry.")

tomAndJerry :: Reader String String
tomAndJerry = do
    t <- tom
    j <- jerry
    return (t ++ "\n" ++ j)

runJerryRun :: String
runJerryRun = (runReader tomAndJerry) "Who is this?"
```

In this example, `tom:: Reader (String -> String)`. So

```
do
    t <- tom
    j <- jerry
    return (t ++ "\n" ++ j)
```

is the same as (supposing `tom` is `Reader (f)` and `jerry` is `Reader (g)`):

```
Reader (f) >>= (\t -> (Reader (g) >>= (\j -> (return (t ++ "\n" ++ j)))))
```

this means that `f` is bound to `t` and `g` to `j`. So both `t` and `j` are function. How can `++` sum two functions?

Comment: well `tom` is not `:: Reader (String -> String)` - you did define it as `:: Reader String String` - so you are concatenating `String`s

Comment: @Carsten why on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67564274/10116440 he made `MyReader String String` be `MyReader f` where `f` is `String -> String`? I'm confused on `MyReader String String` vs `MyReader (String -> String)`

Comment: you can think of `Reader String String` as a function `String -> String` as it is implemented (as a slightly more complicated version as a monad-transformer) like this - the `MyReader f` part there is the a *value*  of `Reader String String` (`MyReader` there is the **data-constructor**) and *not* the type (the type is `Reader String String`)

Comment: `Reader f >>= \t -> ...` does not bind `f` to `t` like you claim. The definition of `>>=` makes it to be equal to `Reader (\x -> let t = f x in ...)`, so `t` is bound to `f x` where `x` is the implicit read-only variable.

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking of `>>=` as being a substitute for `let ... in ...` notation, which is dramatically underselling it. To understand what's going on, let's look at the simplest example.

```hs
useTom :: Reader String String
useTom = do t <- tom
            return (t ++ " we used Tom!")
```

This desugars to

```hs
tom >>= (\t -> return (t ++ " we used Tom!"))
```

How are we adding a `Reader String String` to a `String` using `++`? Assuming `tom = Reader f` as you did, this is equivalent to

```hs
(Reader f) >>= (\t -> return (t ++ " we used Tom!"))
```

Is `++` adding a function to a `String`?

The answer is a definitive `no`.

What is the type of `>>=`? It is `Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. In our case, `>>=` takes the particular type of `Reader String String -> (String -> Reader String String) -> Reader String String`.

In other words, when we are writing

```hs
tom >>= (\t -> return (t ++ " we used Tom!"))
```

The variable `t` must have type `String`, since the second argument of `>>=` must be of type `String -> Reader String String`. Thus, `++` is in fact adding two `String`s together.

We see the same situation here:

```hs
tomMaybe :: Maybe String
tomMaybe = Just "This is Tom."

useTomMaybe :: Maybe String
useTomMaybe = do t <- tomMaybe
                 return (t ++ " we used Tom!")
```

Notice that `useTomMaybe` is exactly the same code as `useTom`. It desurgars to

```hs
useTomMaybe = tomMaybe >>= (\t -> return (t ++ " we used Tom!"))
```

In this case, `>>=` takes on type `Maybe String -> (String -> Maybe String) -> Maybe String`. The function `\t -> return (t ++ " we used Tom!")` has type `String -> Maybe String`: once again, `t` takes on type `String` and `++` adds two `Strings` together.

Comment: why on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67564274/10116440 he made `MyReader String String` be `MyReader f` where `f` is `String -> String`? I'm confused on `MyReader String String` vs `MyReader (String -> String)`

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs This is a confusing aspect of Haskell. Haskell has two different "namespaces" for things that start with capital letters. One is for the names of types. The other is for constructors of types. For example, consider `data MyString = MyString String`. I have actually defined two *different* things here - I have defined a type called `MyString` and a constructor `MyString :: String -> String`. Here, there's a type `MyReader String String` and also a value `MyReader :: (String -> String) -> MyReader String String`.

Comment: if `m` is a monad, then how does `m a` matches with `Reader String String`? There are 2 free variables on `Reader`, how can it match to `m a` where there is just one free variable `a`?

Comment: Do you mean the constructor `MyString :: String -> MyString String`?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Sorry, I did indeed mean `MyString :: String -> MyString`. As for how `m a` matches with `Reader String String`, the `m` is `Reader String` and the `a` is `String`.